# Is it possible to use a curvature map to create high poly model from a low poly?

Tags: baking

I have a low poly mesh, it shows up great when the curvature map from the high poly model is applied and, due to data storage failure the high poly model was lost.
Is there a way to use the curvature map to create real mesh topology so something close to the original mesh could be created and edited?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a subsurf modifier, set to higher levels, such as 3 or 4, and then add a displace modifier, using uv and using your map texture.  Adjust the strength, and if you are happy with it and want true geometry you can apply all the modifiers.